# JqueryUI autotomplete Delegate with focus using arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Im on this project that uses jqueryui to display few auto-complete list when the first letter is pressed. 
 The up and down arrow keys can be used to navigate through the list generated, but i want to fire a `focus` event on the `<li>...</li>` generated by jquery. 
I have tried with the `hover` and `mouseenter` events and it works great. But when i try with `focus`, it wount work
Here's my code

JQuery

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-menu-item a', 'focus', function( event ){
    alert( event.type );
    var item_name_this = $(this).html();

    /*$.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'process.php',
        data : 'item_name_this='+item_name_this,
        cache: false,
        success : function(results){
            $('#div1').html(results);
        }
    });*/

});
```

HTML

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="20%" align="center" id="" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname" value="" placeholder="Item Name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="autocomplete_lists"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="item_info">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" align="center" width="100%" height="100%" id="itemproperties">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="70%">Item Name</td>
                                    <td width="30%"><span id="properties_item_name"></span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Item Quantity</td>
                                    <td><span id="properties_item_qty">&nbsp;</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Item Price</td>
                                    <td><span id="properties_item_price">&nbsp;</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Item Warehouse</td>
                                    <td><span id="properties_item_warehosue">&nbsp;</span></td>
                                </tr>                                                                                                
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

***Forgot to include my CSS in case you'll want to try it locally***

```
.item_info{
    height:250px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}

#itemproperties td{
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    border-right:1px solid #999;
}

#itemproperties td span{
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-size:22px;
}

input{
    height:28px;
}

table{
/*  border-collapse:collapse;*/
}

.autocomplete_lists{
    height:250px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
enter code here
```

Javscript

```
var tags = [ "A-PLAS 800MG","B-PLAS JR","CICOF SYRUP","DBIDEC (NEW U.K)","EBSORBENT GUAZE","ABYCOLD SYR","ABYCOLD TABS","ABYTAB","BBYVITA CAP","CBYVITA SYRUP","DCCULOL EYE 0.5%","ECIDOM CAP LUEX","ECINIL ''0''SUSPENSION","FCINIL '0'SUSPENSION","ACNEGON GEL","GCRIFLAVINE LOTION","FCTIFAST CAP","FCTIFED EXPECTORANT","HCTIFED SYRUP","HCTIFED TAB", ];
$( "#itemname" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
            response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
                return matcher.test( item );
            }) );
        }
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCd4J/) that works with the `mouseenter` event. 
Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery UI AutoComplete has it's own focus event.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  focus: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCd4J/13/) for your scenario

Comment: Pls what should i do in this case is there any alternative to get it to work?

Comment: The DOM Events page on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events) mentions a more generic  focusin event which is also supported by jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/focusin/). Could be worth a try

Comment: The `focusin` Similar to HTML `focus event`, but can be applied to any focusable element. Ive tried that too but not working. is there any other way? :(

Comment: Look at the example in the jsFiddle in my updated answer, the focusin event fires when I tab from the input to the anchor tag, is this not what you're after?

Comment: No please, when the autocomplete list if displayed and you use the arrow keys to navigate through the list, the `focusin` event should fire an a focused item. Please can you give me the updated jsfiddle link.

Comment: Updated my answer, it looks like the jQuery UI AutoComplete wraps the focus event of the underlying Html with it's own focus event which you need to use instead.

Comment: its true that the `focusin` event fires when the tab key is pressed, in my case, the up/down arrow keys are used. The tab key will close the autocomplete list if pressed. :(

Comment: Does the updated jsFiddle which uses the AutoComplete controls focus event resolve the problem?

Comment: Now the arrow key is able to focus on the `<li>` list but i need to get the content of the `<li><a>...</a></li>` to use with ajax. but not working. `$(this).html();`

Comment: @FrancisMarfo  Use **$(this).val();** But i got previous value.

Comment: @LakshmanaKumar It worked great, but there is this trouble, it seems to alert the previous item when you focus on the next item, see updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/VCd4J/14/

Comment: @FrancisMarfo  I too got same problem. We have to approach in different way. But i dont know that.

Comment: @LakshmanaKumar Thank a lot for you Help.. My reputation too small i would have voted up answer

Comment: @FrancisMarfo  No problem. I didnt post post answer. I just helped u.